# How do I reorder the columns of a DataGrid?

Tags: c#, .net, datagrid

How do I reorder the columns of a `System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By writing new data into the grid in the desired order.

Consider using a `DataGridView` instead.  It has much better sorting capabilities.

Comment: He want to order the columns, not sort the rows (atleast thats what the question says :) )

Comment: I think my answer is still going to be the same, except that the DataGridView won't help much for columns.

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense. The data is already in the grid.

Comment: You've got to take the existing data out of the grid, and put new data there.  The `DataGrid` doesn't have column reorder capabilities.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you bind a datatable then you can change column order as

```
dataTable.Columns["Column Name"].SetOrdinal(NewIndex);
```

You need to set DataSource null and clean the GridView before you bind it back

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
```

Comment: I have a DataGrid, not a DataGridView. There is no Columns property.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the column DisplayIndex to some integer in your datacontext.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" DisplayIndex="{Binding Path=DisplayIndex_Name}" />
```

In code behind you can just change the value of the bound parameter, in this case `DisplayIndex_Name` and the bound DisplayIndex of the DataGridTextColumn will also change depending on what value you give it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.displayindex.aspx